# Incorrect syntax whilst using Dapper

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

Firstly, I've ran the query against a database and the results are fine.

The model has two properties attached to it {Skip, Take} and are populated with values at the time of execution, however the async query is failing due to:

> Incorrect syntax near @Take

I've tested a simpler query `select * from table where col1 = @Take` and seems to be working perfectly, very odd.

Any ideas?

```
var query = await conn.QueryAsync<ObjectModel>(
@" SELECT TOP @Take * FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS RoNum, * 
FROM table) as p
where @Skip < RoNum ORDER BY p.ID", model);
```

Comment: Not sure what database you are using, but if it's SQL, look at OFFSET/FETCH: https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SQL Server, the [supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) syntax for TOP is the following:

```
SELECT TOP (@Take) * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS RoNum, * FROM table) as p WHERE @Skip < RoNum ORDER BY p.ID
```

It is possible the database you are using is hitting the same limitation.